# Bash script not running when I boot my laptop

Tags: kubuntu, login, kde, external-monitor, sddm

I am new to Linux and I've set it up just how I want it. However, when I am using my laptop at home, login screen appears on both laptop and  external screen. I want it to appear just on my external screen which is my primary. I've done some research and figured that sddm manager has no idea which is my primary screen. So I've wrote this script in **/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup** to force it to be displayed only on my external monitor but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
#!/bin/sh 
# Xsetup - run as root before the login dialog appears


curr=$(xrandr | grep 'HDMI')

## Create a file to check if the script has been launched
echo "Script launched on $(date)" > /tmp/xrandScript.log


## Store the output of xrandr so you can check what the script sees:
xrandr >> /tmp/xrandScript.log

## print the value of the variable to see if it is what you expect
echo "The variable 'curr' has: $curr"  >> /tmp/xrandScript.log

#Nvidia graphics mode (gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
h="HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

#intel graphics (non gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
l="HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

if [ "$l" = "$curr" ]; then
        echo "Entered lower settings block" >> /tmp/xrandScript.log
        xrandr --output eDP-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
elif [ "$h" = "$curr" ]; then
        echo "Entered higher settings block" >> /tmp/xrandScript.log
        xrandr --output eDP-1-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
else
        echo "ERROR: unknown configuration: $curr"  >> /tmp/xrandScript.log
fi
```

**/etc/sddm.conf**

```
[XDisplay]
# Xsetup script path
# A script to execute when starting the display server
DisplayCommand=/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Debuggin info which Terdon told me to post:

```
Script launched on Wed Jan 13 15:00:03 CET 2021
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
  1680x1050 (0x49) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1440x900 (0x52) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
        v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
  1280x1024 (0x51) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x5e) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1152x864 (0x60) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
        v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
  1024x768 (0x66) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x75) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x84) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
The variable 'curr' has: HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
Entered lower settings block
```

I figured it out!

I wrote `xrandr --output eDP-1 -off`
instead of `xrandr --output eDP-1 --off`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file is executable and owned by `root`? `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` 

Comment: @Matigo everything in that directorium is owned by root and executable

Comment: @steeldriver still nothing

Comment: This is either the bash issue that steeldriver pointed out (but you also need to change the `==` to `=` to have it work, see my answer) or that the output of `xrandr` isn't what you expect. Try the script from my answer and if it doesn't work, try the second one with the debugging info, then add the results to your question and we can take it from there.

Comment: @terdon there it is, still no result

Comment: @kosingas OK, that's great! We now know that the script runs and that `xrandr` is there in the path etc. Now, add debug echo statements in each `if` condition to see if the script enters any of them. Does it? Also, did you add the final `else` I have in my answer? Please show us the exact script you are running now so we can understand.

Comment: @terdon it appears that script is now entering if statement

Comment: @Kosingas I'm pretty sure you do this in `xorg.conf`

Comment: @kosingas do you mean that it works? Or it enters the `if`, runs the `xrandr` command but doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @terdon I sincerly apologise for late reply. It enters if and runs xrandr the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a bash script, it's an `sh` script. On Ubuntu, `sh` is a very basic, POSIX compliant shell called `dash`. Your script, however, is using bash-specific features so `sh` cannot run it. The simplest fix is to change the shebang line to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Alternatively, remove the bashisms. Change `[[` to `[` and `==` to `=`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
curr=$(xrandr | grep 'HDMI')

#Nvidia graphics mode (gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
h="HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

#intel graphics (non gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
l="HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

if [ "$l" = "$curr" ]; then
        xrandr --output eDP-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
elif [ "$h" = "$curr" ]; then
        xrandr --output eDP-1-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
else
    echo "ERROR: unknown configuration: $curr"
fi
```

I also added a final else so you can catch unexpected behavior and changed your variable names to avoid using CAPS. Since, by convention, global environment shell variables are capitalized, it is good practice not to use all caps for your own variable names in shell scripts to avoid variable name collisions.

If this still doesn't work, then the output of `xrandr` when the script runs is likely not what you expect. So add some basic debugging:

```
#!/bin/sh
## Create a file to check if the script has been launched
echo "Script launched on $(date)" > /tmp/xrandScript.log


## Store the output of xrandr so you can check what the script sees:
xrandr >> /tmp/xrandScript.log

curr=$(xrandr | grep 'HDMI')

## print the value of the variable to see if it is what you expect
echo "The variable '$curr' has: $curr"  >> /tmp/xrandScript.log

#Nvidia graphics mode (gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
h="HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

#intel graphics (non gaming mode) xrandr | grep 'HDMI' result
l="HDMI-1-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm"

if [ "$l" = "$curr" ]; then
        xrandr --output eDP-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-1-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
elif [ "$h" = "$curr" ]; then
        xrandr --output eDP-1-1 -off
        xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
else
    echo "ERROR: unknown configuration: $curr"  >> /tmp/xrandScript.log
fi
```

Now, restart your X server or just reboot so the script is launched and check if the `/tmp/xrandScript.log` file is created and if its contents are what you expect.